# find outwhich link on another page was clicked to get to current page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Assuming I have two html pages. Let's assume `foo.html` and `bar.html`. `foo.html` is linked twice to `bar.html`. One from a picture and the other from text content. If a user now clicks on one of the two links on the first page (`foo.html`) and thus gets to `bar.html`, can you find out in bar.html which link the user followed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a query string to the links, e.g.

`foo.html?picture`
`foo.html?text`
then window.location.search will contain `'?picture'` or `'?text'`